# MySQLi returns erroneous results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I've encountered a problem while using mysqli and I can't figure it out why this is happening.

On a MariaDB 5.5.41 server I have a table tbl1

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 1
```

I've created the following PHP script:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="user";
$db_pass="pass";
$db_db="db_test";

// mysqli test
$db_link = @new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_db);

if($db_link->connect_error) die("mysqli connect error");

$result = $db_link->query("SELECT a FROM tbl1 WHERE b='1'");
if(!$result) {
  die("mysqli query error");
} else {
  die("Row count:".$result->num_rows);
}
?>
```

And the result is:

```
Row count:0
```

But if I use the following code:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="user";
$db_pass="pass";
$db_db="db_test";

//mysql
$db_link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$db_link) die("mysql connect error");
mysql_select_db($db_db,$db_link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT a FROM tbl1 WHERE b='1'");
if(!$result) {
  die("mysql query error");
} else {
  die("Row count:".mysql_num_rows($result));
}
?>
```

And the result is:

```
Row count:1
```

Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: **WARNING**: Unless you have a really good reason, do not use the `@` error suppression feature of PHP. This will hide errors that might be important.

Comment: His use of `@` is reasonable for the `mysql` code -- he takes control, tests it, and takes action.  For `mysqli` it is somewhat broken, since it immediately uses an `NULL` `$db_link` as a pointer.

Comment: @Rick I did test the `$db_link` and it is not `NULL`, but I did find some issues with the `mysqli` library, changed it to an older version and now it works.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issues you found in `mysqli` !

Comment: Which phpversion you are using?

Comment: At the time of this issue I was using PHP 5.6.4 built from source. I've replaced it with 5.5.23. But since then I've got back to 5.6 and now I'm using 5.6.11 and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score -2):

mysqli_fetch_row in PHP Manual [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Comment: The problem was not with fetching data from the result it was with the fact that the result was empty when using mysqli.